# Vuforia - AR contour highlighting in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

While developing an AR app using Vuforia, I am unsure on the way to go to add specific contour highlighting effects as the one showcased in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LDlQ1GcRaGk (for example green outline on doors). I am working with a general Area target for the main scene, however I have only encountered the documentation for such effects on Model Targets. I am wondering if I have to specifically generate Model Targets of the needed objects and then incorporate them on the general Area Target ?

I tried transforming the point cloud that generated the Area Target to a SLT format which I could extract the specific components I need to highlight from using Blender, however the size of the point cloud is way too big for such processing.

Comment: I am pretty sure that all doors have the same size and they simply manually placed those effect frames to the specific 3D locations of the doors in their scene / model and then simply enable/disable them based on camera distance. Afaik Vuforia is solely used to align your AR content with the real world area target ... you are still responsible yourself for the content itself ;)

Comment: Vuforia engine has a small library of Visual Effect examples. You will not find the exact thing you want but you could get some inspiration https://library.vuforia.com/unity-extension/vuforia-vfx-library